# How to enable RSA-SHA1 support on OAuth libaray of PHP settings

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have enable the OAuth library php_oauth-1.2.3-5.5-ts-vc11-x86. But RSA-SHA1 not supported.

I am using windows-7 enterprise verison 64 bit. I am trying to enable it on my local machine.

Below are the some reference link but no solution-:

http://grokbase.com/t/php/pecl-dev/12726kzy4y/oauth-dll-for-windows-for-php-5-4-4.

http://php.net/oauth

http://oauth.net/code/
[image]

Comment: Is the openssl extension installed?

Comment: Yes openssl is installed.

Comment: @neubert openssl extension installed for me, still i am getting error, can you pls help me?